# trying to uninstall my uwp using powershell

Tags: powershell, uwp

I'm doing a task that relies on the ability to uninstall my UWP using a powershell script.
Checking this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=win10-ps

and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=win10-ps

I went to try this:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package "59777724-81d4-406d-95d7-be70af1xxxxx" -AllUsers
```

or even this

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package $fullName -user username
```

And yes, app name is a GUID - I inherit this and its fine by me.
Also, this is a side load app. 
Now... regardless I use both `"-AllUsers"` or `"-user someUser"` the app is been removed but only for the the current, not all or the one I specified. 
Any help on this?

**Update**
If I try this

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package $AppDisplayName -AllUsers
```

I had an error, saying the package is not found.  (Excepção de HRESULT: 0x80073CF1)

If I try:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package $AppDisplayName -User username
```

I had the error that id structure is invalid.

Comment: After `Remove-AppxPackage`, you might also need  to use `Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage` perhaps?  I don't have time to test this specific one

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but are you an admin on the computer you're running this on / are you running PowerShell in an elevated session?  Otherwise it may not have access to user profiles other than the current user...

Comment: @JohnLBevan yes - i'm running it as admin and also, i'm admin to this machine.

Answer (score 3):

Just on the chance to clarify my comment (without testing by me) try this in Powershell run as Administrator

```
Get-AppxPackage -Allusers -Package "59777724-81d4-406d-95d7-be70af1xxxxx"  | Remove-AppxPackage

Get-AppxProvisionedPackage –Online -Package "59777724-81d4-406d-95d7-be70af1xxxxx"| Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage –Online
```

Comment: if you do 
`Get-AppxPackage -Allusers -Package "59777724-81d4-406d-95d7-be70af1xxxxx"  | Remove-AppxPackage`

it will only remove for the current user